# Android Studio 3.5 can't open previous version projects

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

I have a project stored in GitHub, it was created a few days ago using *Android Studio 3.3.*

I have installed *Android Studio 3.5* on a new Windows, and checked out the project to the disk.

When I open the project in Android Studio 3.5, in Android view I only get an empty `app` item.

[image]

The Project view shows all the files yet it seems the project itself isn't loaded.

[image]

What should I do to load the week-old project in this very best IDE of great improvements?

Comment: You seem to be missing a top-level `.iml` file. Try File > Sync Project with Gradle Files to see if that will rebuild it. If not, and if your Git repo contains `.idea/` or `.iml` files, you might try checking out the project (outside of Studio), deleting the `.idea/` and `.iml` files from the checked-out repo, then import that project into Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, the key word was **importing**. So what is the difference between _Opening an existing Android Studio project_ and _Import projects_? I would expect the former to work and not needed the latter...

Comment: AFAICT, "open" will assume existing `.idea/` and `.iml` stuff is good, while "import" does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then it seems, the _Open..._ feature is buggy yet :/

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't even open new projects !

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Android Studio Launcher; or use File -> New -> **Import Project**
2. Select "**Import Project**"
3. Select project folder
4. Follow next steps *you understand another

*When I have same problem, I use this steps to solve it.*